# while i'm using vscode shortcuts ,it gets mad

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using vscode and I'm just learning how to code.but the problem is my vscode doesn't work correctly .when I'm going to use shortcut keys like ctrl+A or ctrl+C ,the editor works in a different way(I can't wirte or delete anything) and I just can move over the words without any change.

Comment: looks like you have installed something like Vim-Mode

Comment: oh man.exactly ....thanks alot